# function as argument of another function

Tags: python, function, arguments, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I have a code that in part of it a function is passed to another function as an argument. when I run this code I get this error:

```
h() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'
```

In this part I call h function as a parameter of another function(train of engine class):

```
engine.train(h, train_loader, opt.epochs, optimizer)
```

and h is this piece of code:

```
def h(sample, id):
    inputs = utils.cast(sample[0], opt.dtype).detach()
    targets = utils.cast(sample[1], 'long')
    if opt.teacher_id != '':
        if id==1:
            y_s, y_t, loss_groups = utils.data_parallel(f, inputs, params, sample[2], range(opt.ngpu))
            loss_groups = [v.sum() for v in loss_groups]
            [m.add(v.item()) for m, v in zip(meters_at, loss_groups)]
            return utils.distillation(y_s, y_t, targets, opt.temperature, opt.alpha)+sum(loss_groups), y_s

        if id==2:
            y_s1, y_t1, loss_groups1 = utils.data_parallel(f1, inputs, params1, sample[2], range(opt.ngpu))
            loss_groups1 = [v.sum() for v in loss_groups1]
            [m.add(v.item()) for m, v in zip(meters_at, loss_groups1)]
            return utils.distillation(y_s1, y_t1, targets, opt.temperature, opt.alpha)+sum(loss_groups1), y_s1

        if id==3:
            y_s2, y_t2, loss_groups2 = utils.data_parallel(f2, inputs, params2, sample[2], range(opt.ngpu))
            loss_groups2 = [v.sum() for v in loss_groups2]
            [m.add(v.item()) for m, v in zip(meters_at, loss_groups2)]
            return utils.distillation(y_s2, y_t2, targets, opt.temperature, opt.alpha)+sum(loss_groups2), y_s2

    else:
        if id==1:
            y = utils.data_parallel(f, inputs, params, sample[2], range(opt.ngpu))[0]
        if id==2:
            y = utils.data_parallel(f1, inputs, params1, sample[2], range(opt.ngpu))[0]
        if id==3:
            y = utils.data_parallel(f2, inputs, params2, sample[2], range(opt.ngpu))[0]

        return F.cross_entropy(y, targets), y
```

Comment: Where did you call h()?

Comment: So some function is calling `h` and that call fails? You don't have to show us all of the complications of `h`, it could be mocked with `def h(sample, id): pass`. What's important is the caller that seems not to have included the required parameters for `h`.

Comment: that is included in the post:engine.train(h, train_loader, opt.epochs, optimizer)

Comment: You should have gotten a detailed traceback message with the error. Post that along with relevant calling code so we can see what happens.

Comment: engine.train(h, train_loader, opt.epochs, optimizer)....this segment of code is calling h

Comment: Its likely that "engine", whatever that is, requires a function with a different call signature than what you passed.

Comment: https://github.com/pytorch/tnt/blob/master/torchnet/engine/engine.py